# function in vba excel not working correctly five #value

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have this VBA function

```vb
Function SearchString(src As String, rng As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim output As String
     
    ' Remove spaces from source string
    src = Replace(src, " ", "")
    
    ' Loop through cells in range
    For Each cell In rng
        ' Remove spaces from cell value
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "")
        
        ' Check if whole text is matched
        If src = cell.Value Then
          output = cell.Row
          Exit For
        End If
        
        ' Check if first 13 characters match
        If Len(src) >= 13 And Left(src, 13) = Left(cell.Value, 13) Then
          output = cell.Row
          Exit For
        End If
        
        ' Check if first 11 characters match
        If Len(src) >= 11 And Left(src, 11) = Left(cell.Value, 11) Then
          output = cell.Row
          Exit For
        End If
        
        ' Check if first 9 characters match
        If Len(src) >= 9 And Left(src, 9) = Left(cell.Value, 9) Then
          output = cell.Row
          Exit For
        End If
        
        ' Check if first 7 characters match
        If Len(src) >= 7 And Left(src, 7) = Left(cell.Value, 7) Then
          output = cell.Row
          Exit For
        End If    
    Next cell
    
    ' Return result
    If output = "" Then
      SearchString = "No match"
    Else
      SearchString = output
    End If
End Function
```

and when i called like

```vb
=SearchString(N4,H2:H21)
```

where N4 has text value "ahmed ali hassan"
and range h2:h21 has list of names

This yields `#value`.

I want to search list of names and search for whole text then without spaces then with first 13 letters and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the line: cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", ""). You can use a auxiliar variable, example, auxString = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "") and replace all cell.Value by auxString.